# Laptop boots to empty boot menu

Tags: linux, windows, boot

I have a laptop that is dual booted with Windows and Linux. My laptop froze suddenly and I was forced to restart it. I was then taken straight to the bios menu which never happens. When I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> at startup to get to the boot menu my laptop did not have any options in the boot menu. What is going on?

[image]

Comment: Please boot some Linux distro from USB and check if your disk partitions look healthy. Also check disk's SMART params.

Comment: Do you still see the hard drive being listed on any of the pages/tabs if you `Enter Setup`?

Comment: Just did and the only partition showing is my USB stick

Answer (score -1):

You should provide some more information such as what task was running lastly, what file you downloaded from internet etc. However, this problem is caused when your hard drive gets corrupted. Now, you need to recover the hard drive files. Boot from live media of any linux according to your choice. Then try the recovery tool of that os to recover.

To know the cause you may lookup [here](https://www.gillware.com/hard-drive-data-recovery/boot-device-not-found/) or [here](https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/restore-data-when-hard-drive-not-detected-in-bios.html). You can try [this](https://www.simplified.guide/linux/disk-recover-partition-table#:%7E:text=A%20lost%20or%20deleted%20partition,such%20as%20the%20Ubuntu%20installer.) solution.